# Need clarification on a singleton instance as it does have a static property instantiated to the same class

Tags: ios, swift

How is testScore (given below in class definition for SandwichStore class) a singleton instance  as it does have a static property instantiated to the same class?

I am new to SwiftUI and fairly ok with Swift. As I was coding along with the WWDC SwiftUI video tutorial, I could not understand how is testScore a singleton instance here? Why doesn't it have a shared static property which instantiates the class something like in API class?

```
import Foundation
class SandwichStore {
    var sandwiches: [Sandwich]
    
    init(sandwiches:[Sandwich] = []) {
        self.sandwiches = sandwiches
    }
    
    let testScore = SandwichStore(sandwiches: testData)
}




class API
{
    static let shared = API()
    var isRequestPending = false

    private init() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at the code in the WWDC session video you will see that `testStore` is outside of the class definition.

The actual code is:

```
class SandwichStore {
    var sandwiches: [Sandwich]
    
    init(sandwiches:[Sandwich] = []) {
        self.sandwiches = sandwiches
    }
}

let testStore = SandwichStore(sandwiches: testData)
```

Despite what the presenter says, `testStore` isn't a singleton, it is actually a global constant.  The presenter probably just misspoke.

If `SandwichStore` adopted a singleton pattern then it wouldn't be possible to instantiate the store needed to run the app *and* the test store.

A singleton is an instance of a class, so at best a global can hold a reference to a singleton instance.

Comment: I haven’t looked at this presentation lately, so there may be more than one instance, but a global constant can be a singleton.

Comment: A singleton would mean that you can only have exactly one SandwichStore (not possible to instantiate more than one), "Singleton" doesn't mean that there is one in global scope.

Comment: @Jessy, is there an example to illustrate a case where a global constant is being used as a singleton?

Comment: A global constant can't be a singleton per se. You can assign a reference to a singleton to a global constant.  E.g. `let app = UIApplication.shared`. `app` holds a reference to the singleton `UIApplication` object but it is not the singleton itself.

Comment: I've mostly seen it with opaque "instances of protocols", e.g. [in Metal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/1433401-mtlcreatesystemdefaultdevice). @Paulw11 is using a common, specialized, and best practice approach for organizing where a singleton is found. But all that "singleton" means is that there is one. It doesn't matter what namespace it's in, for it to fit that description. In Apple's languages, there's not actually a way to enforce that others can't be created.

Comment: The standard approach in Swift is to declare the initialiser as private, thereby preventing instantiation of the object except via the singleton instance  static property.  It is true that sometimes this approach is not available if inheritance is involved, but that is not the case here.